# Determine whether a property possessed by every term in a convergent sequence is necessarily inherited by the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having difficulty coming up with actual sequences that have the properties below. I've included my thoughts on the questions below.

Assume that $(a_n)\rightarrow a$.

1. If every $a_n$ is an upper bound for a set $B$, then $a$ is also an upper bound for $B$

Is it possible to construct a *strictly decreasing* sequence, in which all of the terms are upper bounds, but the limit point is less than the supremum of $B$?

2. If every $a_n$ is the complement of the interval $(0,1)$, then $a$ is also in 
   the complement of $(0,1).$

I'm actually not sure what to consider at all here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Weak inequalities are preserved in the limit, so if for any $b \in B$, $a_n \geq b$ for all $n$, then $a \geq b$.

An way to see that $a\geq \sup B$ is to suppose that $\sup B > a$. Then, we could find a neighborhood around $a$ such that the entire neighborhood is below $\sup B$. Since $a$ is a limit point, there must be an $a_n$ in this neighborhood, but then $a_n$ would not be an upper bound of $B$, since it is less than the least upper bound.

2. $(0,1)$ is an open set, so $(0,1)^c$ is closed. This means that any convergent sequence in $(0,1)^c$ converges to a point in $(0,1)^c$.

Suppose that $a \in (0,1)$. Then, pick some $0<\epsilon<\max(|a-0|, |a-1|)$. The ball of radius $\epsilon$ must lie entirely in $(0,1)$, and there must be a point in the sequence of $a_n$'s that lies in this ball, because $a$ is a limit point. So there is a point in the sequence that does not lie in $(0,1)^c$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the supB = b  and since every term of the sequence is an
   upper bound of B so, it implies that b –an ≤0.
   Then lim(b–an) ≤ 0
   i.e, b–a ≤ 0
   i.e. b ≤ a
   So, a is an upper bound for B.